# Opengl ES color blend mode

Tags: android, opengl-es, color-blending

I've got a particle system being rendered on top of a background texture. Each particle is a square and has no texture applied to it and they are all the same color. The background is a grayscale texture.
What I'm trying to achieve is the same type of blending, known in applications such as Gimp, as color blend mode.

Basically, the area of the background covered by a particle should maintain it's luminance, but adopt the color of the particle.
I've tried several combinations of parameter of glBlendFunc() and tried messing around with glTexEnv, but I'm having a lot of trouble understanding it.
Currently, if two particles overlap, they either become brighter or darker (depending on the glBlendFunc parameters).

I'm using OpenGL ES 1.1 on android. Is there any way of achieving this effect without having to use OpenGL ES 2.0? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 0):

glBlendFunc only supports separable blend modes. Hue-only blending is non-separable, so it cannot be expressed in standard OpenGL. See [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/Mark_Kilgard/blend-modes-for-opengl) by Nvidia's Mark Kilgard, slide 41.

Nvidia provides an extension on its newer GPUs (incl. Tegra), called [NV_blend_equation_advanced](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/NV/blend_equation_advanced.txt) which adds the `GL_HSL_HUE_NV` and `GL_HSL_COLOR_NV` tokens to perform the operation you are describing. Given that you wish to maintain support for OpenGL ES 1.1, this is not actually an option for you.

However, there may be a way to achieve the effect you are describing, given that your background is grayscale:

1. convert your particle color from RGB to the HSL color space
2. maximize the luminance in HSL (i.e. set it to <s>1.0</s> 0.5)
3. convert back to RGB. This will be your actual particle color
4. paint your particle with a multiply blend operation: `glBlendFunc(GL_DST_COLOR, GL_ZERO)`

This should maintain luminance while painting the background with the color of the particle.

Edit: `glBlendFunc(GL_DST_COLOR, GL_SRC_COLOR)` would give 2 * source * destination color which might help.

Edit 2: try [glTexEnvf](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glTexEnv.xml) as follows

1. Render background with `glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE)`
2. Render particle using `glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE)`

It has been more than a decade since I last used glTexEnv, but there might be a combination of parameters that can achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: In step two, if I maximize luminance in HSL, don't I get pure white? Converting back to RGB I get (255,255,255). So I tried using the HSV color space and maximizing the value, but the background becomes darker when the particles overlap.

Comment: You are right, in HSL that should be a lightness of 0.5, not 1.0 (which is pure white). HSV with a value of 1.0 should give the same result. The idea is that multiplication with a pure color should result in no change of lightness. This only works for pure colors (you can verify that easily with e.g. RGB = (255,0,0).)

Comment: I get the desired effect, but only with colors (255,0,0), (0,255,0) and (0,0,255). If I use something like (204,0,255), which is (288º, 100%, 50%) in HSL, the overlap becomes darker.

Comment: After playing around a bit more, it seems the only colors where the overlap doesn't become darker, are those where a channel is either set to 255 or 0 (i.e. 255,0,0; 255,255,0; 255,0,255, etc.) Any more ideas I could try?

Comment: Ah, I just realized that [glTexEnv](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glTexEnv.xml) is available in OpenGL ES 1.1. I thought it was only available in desktop OpenGL. See my edit on the post above for another potential solution.

Comment: I was already using GL_REPLACE to render the background, so it wouldn't be affected by gl_color. As for GL_MODULATE or any other texture environment to render the particles, it really doesn't seem to change anything, since the particles have no texture... Maybe I should use a white texture and use GL_TEXTURE_ENV_COLOR to set their color. I'll try this now.

Comment: No luck. All the texture environment is define how the textures are applied and not how they are blended, so all I can do with glTexEnv is define the particles color...